# Using threads to make database requests

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, javafx

I'm trying to understand how threads works in java. This is a simple database request that returns a ResultSet. I'm using JavaFx.

```
    package application;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Controller{
    @FXML
    private Button getCourseBtn;
    @FXML
    private TextField courseId;
    @FXML
    private Label courseCodeLbl;
    private ModelController mController;

    private void requestCourseName(){
        String courseName = "";
        Course c = new Course();
        c.setCCode(Integer.valueOf(courseId.getText()));
        mController = new ModelController(c);
        try {
            ResultSet rs = mController.<Course>get();
            if(rs.next()){
                courseCodeLbl.setText(rs.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//      return courseName;
    }

    public void getCourseNameOnClick(){
        try {
//              courseCodeLbl.setText(requestCourseName());
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    requestCourseName();
                }
            }, "Thread A");
            t.start();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

This returns an exception:

> Exception in thread "Thread A" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread A

How do I correctly implement threading so that every database request is executed in a second thread instead of the main thread?

I've heard of implementing Runnable but then how do I invoke different methods in run method?

Never worked with threading before but I thought it's time for it.

Comment: Why do you want to run the query in a second thread when it looks like you'll need the result in the current thread?

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Typically, accessing databases is a long-running process, so it should not be done on the FX Application Thread (as it will make the UI unresponsive). So the OP's instinct is correct here: execute the long-running process on another thread: (s)he just needs to schedule the processing of the results back on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: Mnemonics: I don't really understand what your actual example is supposed to do. You read a bunch of rows from the database, and for each row set the text of a (single, fixed) label. The net result (if you fix the threading error) is that the label would just show the value of the last row read from the database; all the other rows are just discarded. I provided a high-level answer to your question (which I think is actually what you seem to be looking for), but I deliberately didn't reference your example as I don't really know what it's supposed to do.

Comment: The query is this: "select c_name from course where c_code = 1". Because the c_code is pk in the table it only returns one row. Nothing advanced. I do understand your confusion, I've used 'while' instead of 'if' and I apologize for the confusion. I will edit my question. I will go through your post in a minute. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Ah, ok, that does make sense then. Updated answer to include that specific case.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**Threading Rules for JavaFX**

There are two basic rules for threads and JavaFX:

1. Any code that modifies or accesses the state of a node that is part of a scene graph **must** be executed on the JavaFX application thread. Certain other operations (e.g. creating new `Stage`s) are also bound by this rule.
2. Any code that may take a long time to run **should** be executed on a background thread (i.e. not on the FX Application Thread).

The reason for the first rule is that, like most UI toolkits, the framework is written without any synchronization on the state of elements of the scene graph. Adding synchronization incurs a performance cost, and this turns out to be a prohibitive cost for UI toolkits. Thus only one thread can safely access this state. Since the UI thread (FX Application Thread for JavaFX) needs to access this state to render the scene, the FX Application Thread is the only thread on which you can access "live" scene graph state. In JavaFX 8 and later, most methods subject to this rule perform checks and throw runtime exceptions if the rule is violated. (This is in contrast to Swing, where you can write "illegal" code and it may appear to run fine, but is in fact prone to random and unpredictable failure at arbitrary time.) ***This is the cause of the `IllegalStateException` you are seeing***: you are calling `courseCodeLbl.setText(...)` from a thread other than the FX Application Thread.

The reason for the second rule is that the FX Application Thread, as well as being responsible for processing user events, is also responsible for rendering the scene. Thus if you perform a long-running operation on that thread, the UI will not be rendered until that operation is complete, and will become unresponsive to user events. While this won't generate exceptions or cause corrupt object state (as violating rule 1 will), it (at best) creates a poor user experience.

Thus if you have a long-running operation (such as accessing a database) that needs to update the UI on completion, the basic plan is to perform the long-running operation in a background thread, returning the results of the operation when it is complete, and then schedule an update to the UI on the UI (FX Application) thread. All single-threaded UI toolkits have a mechanism to do this: in JavaFX you can do so by calling `Platform.runLater(Runnable r)` to execute `r.run()` on the FX Application Thread. (In Swing, you can call `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable r)` to execute `r.run()` on the AWT event dispatch thread.) JavaFX (see later in this answer) also provides some higher-level API for managing the communication back to the FX Application Thread.

**General Good Practices for Multithreading**

The best practice for working with multiple threads is to structure code that is to be executed on a "user-defined" thread as an object that is initialized with some fixed state, has a method to perform the operation, and on completion returns an object representing the result. Using [immutable objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html), in particular, a [`record`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/language/records.html), for the initialized state and computation result is highly desirable. The idea here is to eliminate the possibility of any mutable state being visible from multiple threads as far as possible. Accessing data from a database fits this idiom nicely: you can initialize your "worker" object with the parameters for the database access (search terms, etc). Perform the database query and get a result set, use the result set to populate a collection of domain objects, and return the collection at the end.

In some cases it will be necessary to share mutable state between multiple threads. When this absolutely has to be done, you need to carefully synchronize access to that state to avoid observing the state in an inconsistent state (there are other more subtle issues that need to be addressed, such as liveness of the state, etc). The strong recommendation when this is needed is to use a high-level library to manage these complexities for you.

**Using the javafx.concurrent API**

JavaFX provides a [concurrency API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/package-summary.html) that is designed for executing code in a background thread, with API specifically designed for updating the JavaFX UI on completion of (or during) the execution of that code. This API is designed to interact with the [`java.util.concurrent` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html), which provides general facilities for writing multithreaded code (but with no UI hooks). The key class in `javafx.concurrent` is [`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html), which represents a single, one-off, unit of work intended to be performed on a background thread. This class defines a single abstract method, `call()`, which takes no parameters, returns a result, and may throw checked exceptions. `Task` implements `Runnable` with its `run()` method simply invoking `call()`. `Task` also has a collection of methods which are guaranteed to update state on the FX Application Thread, such as [`updateProgress(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateProgress-long-long-), [`updateMessage(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateMessage-java.lang.String-), etc. It defines some observable properties (e.g. [`state`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#stateProperty--) and [`value`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#valueProperty--)): listeners to these properties will be notified of changes on the FX Application Thread. Finally, there are some convenience methods to register handlers ([`setOnSucceeded(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#setOnSucceeded-javafx.event.EventHandler-), [`setOnFailed(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#setOnFailed-javafx.event.EventHandler-), etc); any handlers registered via these methods will also be invoked on the FX Application Thread.

So the general formula for retrieving data from a database is:

1. Create a `Task` to handle the call to the database.
2. Initialize the `Task` with any state that is needed to perform the database call.
3. Implement the task's `call()` method to perform the database call, returning the results of the call.
4. Register a handler with the task to send the results to the UI when it is complete.
5. Invoke the task on a background thread.

For database access, I strongly recommend encapsulating the actual database code in a separate class that knows nothing about the UI ([Data Access Object design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object)). Then just have the task invoke the methods on the data access object.

So you might have a DAO class like this (note there is no UI code here):

```
public class WidgetDAO {

    // In real life, you might want a connection pool here, though for
    // desktop applications a single connection often suffices:
    private Connection conn ;

    public WidgetDAO() throws Exception {
        conn = ... ; // initialize connection (or connection pool...)
    }

    public List<Widget> getWidgetsByType(String type) throws SQLException {
        try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from widget where type = ?")) {
            pstmt.setString(1, type);
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            List<Widget> widgets = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Widget widget = new Widget();
                widget.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                widget.setNumberOfBigRedButtons(rs.getString("btnCount"));
                // ...
                widgets.add(widget);
            }
            return widgets ;
        }
    }

    // ...

    public void shutdown() throws Exception {
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

Retrieving a bunch of widgets might take a long time, so any calls from a UI class (e.g a controller class) should schedule this on a background thread. A controller class might look like this:

```
public class MyController {

    private WidgetDAO widgetAccessor ;
    
    // java.util.concurrent.Executor typically provides a pool of threads...
    private Executor exec ;

    @FXML
    private TextField widgetTypeSearchField ;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Widget> widgetTable ;

    public void initialize() throws Exception {
        widgetAccessor = new WidgetDAO();

        // create executor that uses daemon threads:
        exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(runnable -> {
            Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t ;
        });
    }

    // handle search button:
    @FXML
    public void searchWidgets() {
        final String searchString = widgetTypeSearchField.getText();
        Task<List<Widget>> widgetSearchTask = new Task<List<Widget>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Widget> call() throws Exception {
                return widgetAccessor.getWidgetsByType(searchString);
            }
        };

        widgetSearchTask.setOnFailed(e -> {
           widgetSearchTask.getException().printStackTrace();
            // inform user of error...
        });

        widgetSearchTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> 
            // Task.getValue() gives the value returned from call()...
            widgetTable.getItems().setAll(widgetSearchTask.getValue()));

        // run the task using a thread from the thread pool:
        exec.execute(widgetSearchTask);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Notice how the call to the (potentially) long-running DAO method is wrapped in a `Task` which is run on a background thread (via the accessor) to prevent blocking the UI (rule 2 above). The update to the UI (`widgetTable.setItems(...)`) is actually executed back on the FX Application Thread, using the `Task`'s convenience callback method [`setOnSucceeded(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#setOnSucceeded-javafx.event.EventHandler-) (satisfying rule 1).

In your case, the database access you are performing returns a single result, so you might have a method like

```
public class MyDAO {

    private Connection conn ; 

    // constructor etc...

    public Course getCourseByCode(int code) throws SQLException {
        try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from course where c_code = ?")) {
            pstmt.setInt(1, code);
            ResultSet results = pstmt.executeQuery();
            if (results.next()) {
                Course course = new Course();
                course.setName(results.getString("c_name"));
                // etc...
                return course ;
            } else {
                // maybe throw an exception if you want to insist course with given code exists
                // or consider using Optional<Course>...
                return null ;
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

And then your controller code would look like

```
final int courseCode = Integer.valueOf(courseId.getText());
Task<Course> courseTask = new Task<Course>() {
    @Override
    public Course call() throws Exception {
        return myDAO.getCourseByCode(courseCode);
    }
};
courseTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
    Course course = courseTask.getCourse();
    if (course != null) {
        courseCodeLbl.setText(course.getName());
    }
});
exec.execute(courseTask);
```

The [API docs for `Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) have many more examples, including updating the `progress` property of the task (useful for progress bars..., etc.

**Related**

- [JavaFX - Background Thread for SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878788/javafx-background-thread-for-sql-query)
- [Sample for accessing a local database from JavaFX using concurrent tasks for database operations so that the UI remains responsive.](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/4957967)

Answer (score 10):

> Exception in thread "Thread A" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread A

The exception is trying to tell you that you are trying to access JavaFX scene graph outside the JavaFX application thread. But where ??

```
courseCodeLbl.setText(rs.getString(1)); // <--- The culprit
```

> If I can't do this how do I use a background thread?

The are different approaches which leads to similar solutions.

### Wrap you Scene graph element with Platform.runLater

There easier and most simple way is to wrap the above line in `Plaform.runLater`, such that it gets executed on JavaFX Application thread.

```
Platform.runLater(() -> courseCodeLbl.setText(rs.getString(1)));
```

### Use Task

The *better approach* to go with these scenarios is to use [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html), which has specialized methods to send back updates. In the following example, I am using `updateMessage` to update the message. This property is bind to `courseCodeLbl` textProperty.

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() {
        String courseName = "";
        Course c = new Course();
        c.setCCode(Integer.valueOf(courseId.getText()));
        mController = new ModelController(c);
        try {
            ResultSet rs = mController.<Course>get();
            if(rs.next()) {
                // update message property
                updateMessage(rs.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public void getCourseNameOnClick(){
    try {
        Thread t = new Thread(task);
        // To update the label
        courseCodeLbl.textProperty.bind(task.messageProperty());
        t.setDaemon(true); // Imp! missing in your code
        t.start();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with database. JavaFx, like pretty much all GUI libraries, requires that you only use the main UI thread to modify the GUI.

You need to pass the data from the database back to the main UI thread. Use Platform.runLater() to schedule a Runnable to be run in the main UI thread.

```
public void getCourseNameOnClick(){
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            String courseName = requestCourseName();
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                courseCodeLbl.setText(courseName)
            });
        }
    }, "Thread A").start();
}
```

Alternatively, you can [use Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784333/platform-runlater-and-task-javafx).