# Threading login button javafx

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, javafx-2

I'm trying to add concurrency using JavaFX. After doing some reading I think that `javafx.concurrent.Task` is what I want.

I would like to be able to update my scene from the thread. When I have this:

```
private void login() {
    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>(){

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Hello");
                    actiontarget.setText("logging in");
                    // login code
            });

            return null;
        }

    };
    Thread t = new Thread(task);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
}
```

The screen lags login code because it is extensive in what it checks. This would be an issue but the login screen also has some animations, so those lag and it looks tacky.

Instead of the above code I have tried this:

```
private void login() {
    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>(){

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            actiontarget.setText("logging in");
            // login code
            return null;
        }

    };
    Thread t = new Thread(task);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
}
```

This does not lag the screen, however, the actiontarget never changes to `logging in` in this case. The terminal still receives `hello`, but it is as if the daemon thread does not have access to the actiontarget even though the compiler throws no errors.

When I dig deeper though, I find that the `failed()` method is being called. Printing the exception yields `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-5`.

Searching further makes it seem as though it needs `Platform.runLater`, but doing so causes lag once again. Is there a way around that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249493/using-threads-to-make-database-requests

Comment: The basic problem here is you are either doing everything in the `Platform.runLater(...)`, or nothing in the `Platform.runLater(...)`. Do the long-running, non-UI code first, then the UI code in the `Platform.runLater(...)`. But read the linked question for a complete explanation.