# Update JavaFX 8 UI / Multithread

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx

for days now i am trying to update a Javafx userinterface while sending 2 or more E-Mails automatically. The UI should update a Label with "connecting", "sending" and "sent". I've read about Runnables, Tasks, TimeLine but i dont really understand which method i should use and how it works.

Everywhere i read about Platform.runLater(), I used it but the animation in my JavaFX Gui freezes and the Label only changes, when all E-Mails have been sent.

I will update this post with my code soon, but can someone already tell me what kind of Thread i should use and how the ui can be updated easily?

//edit

thanks for your help, Branislav but now im getting the "Not on FX application thread"-Error. The following code is not my "extends Application"-class, please take a look.

```
public class ControllerOCM implements Initializable{



    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> comboEmpf;

    @FXML
    private Label lblStatus;

    @FXML
    private Label lblStatus1;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        hint.setText("some hint");
    }

    public void sende(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {

        switch (comboEmpf.getValue()) {
        case "A": System.out.println("A");break;
        case "B":
        File fTEST = new File("C:\\B\\");
        File[] fpathTEST = fTEST.listFiles();
        String[] fnameTEST = fTEST.list();

    for (int i=0; i<fpathTEST.length; i++) {
        SendenTask sendTEST = new SendenTask(mail@address.com,
                "bodycontent",
                "subject", 
                fpathTEST[i].toString(),    
                fnameTEST[i],               
                i,                      //count
                fpathTEST.length);      //max

        new Thread(sendTEST).start();
    }
            break;
        }
    }

     public class SendenTask extends Task<Void> {
            private String adr;
            private String body;
            private String subj;
            private String fp;
            private String fn;
            private int count;
            private int max;

         public SendenTask(String adr, String body, String subj, String fp, String fn, int count, int max) {
            this.adr = adr;
            this.body = body;
            this.subj = subj;
            this.fp = fp;
            this.fn = fn;
            this.count = count;
            this.max = max;

         }

         @Override 
         protected Void call() throws Exception {

         lblStatus1.setText("connecting");
         //doing connectionAction

         lblStatus1.setText("sending");
         updateMessage("sending");
         //doing sendingthingys


         //sending complete
         lblStatus1.setText("sent");
         System.out.println("done");
         updateMessage("done");

             return null;
         }
     }
}
```

//edit2

Now the programm is sending Emails one after another but the textproperty is not working correctly. It is not refreshing the text, it only emptys the label. If i remove the unbind-line (in succeed) it only works one time i run the send task. After that it is empty again for all other send tasks.

```
public class ControllerOCM implements Initializable{



        @FXML
        private ComboBox<String> comboEmpf;

        @FXML
        private Label lblStatus;

        @FXML
        private Label lblStatus1;


        @Override
        public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
            hint.setText("some hint");
        }

        public void sende(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {

            switch (comboEmpf.getValue()) {
            case "A": System.out.println("A");break;
            case "B":
            File fTEST = new File("C:\\B\\");
            File[] fpathTEST = fTEST.listFiles();
            String[] fnameTEST = fTEST.list();

        for (int i=0; i<fpathTEST.length; i++) {
            SendenTask sendTEST = new SendenTask(mail@address.com,
                    "bodycontent",
                    "subject", 
                    fpathTEST[i].toString(),    
                    fnameTEST[i],               
                    i,                      //count
                    fpathTEST.length);      //max

              lblStatus1.textProperty().bind(sendTEST.messageProperty());
              thread = new Thread(sendTEST);
              thread.start();   
              }
              break;
            }
        }

         public class SendenTask extends Task<Void> {
                private String adr;
                private String body;
                private String subj;
                private String fp;
                private String fn;
                private int count;
                private int max;

             public SendenTask(String adr, String body, String subj, String fp, String fn, int count, int max) {
                this.adr = adr;
                this.body = body;
                this.subj = subj;
                this.fp = fp;
                this.fn = fn;
                this.count = count;
                this.max = max;

             }

             @Override 
             protected Void call() throws Exception {

             while(!sending) {
             sending = true

             updateMessage("connecting");
             //doing connectionAction


             updateMessage("sending");
             //doing sendingthingys


             //sending complete
             updateMessage("done");
                 }
                 return null;
             }
     @Override
     protected void succeeded() {
         super.succeeded();
         lblStatus1.textProperty().unbind();
         sending = false;
         }
       }

    }
```

**//edit3
The big question is, where do i put the 
lblStatus1.textProperty().bind(sendTEST.messageProperty());
and where the
lblStatus1.textProperty().unbind();
?**

Comment: Read through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249493/using-threads-to-make-database-requests and see if it helps.

Comment: I updated my question with demo. Hopefully it will make things clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) class.

Here is a small demo. Let's simulate time consuming task via `for` loop:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TaskDemo extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final Label label = new Label();

        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                boolean fxApplicationThread = Platform.isFxApplicationThread();
                System.out.println("Is call on FXApplicationThread: " + fxApplicationThread);
                // Run your time consuming task here!
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    updateMessage("Time elapsed: " + i);
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void succeeded() {
                boolean fxApplicationThread = Platform.isFxApplicationThread();
                System.out.println("Is call on FXApplicationThread: " + fxApplicationThread);
                super.succeeded();
                label.textProperty().unbind();
                label.setText("Task done");
            }
        };
        // Bind messageProperty of task for textProperty of Label
        label.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
        stage.setScene(new Scene(label, 300, 200));
        stage.show();
        new Thread(task).start();

    }
}
```

Things are simple. Your time consuming task will freeze UI until it finishes. By using `Task` class, your time consuming task runs on background thread leaving JavaFX thread responsive. Occasionally, you can "publish" results of your task from `call` method. **DO NOT** update your JavaFX UI on background thread (in `call` method). By calling `Platform.isFxApplicationThread()` you can check whether your code runs on `FXApplicationThread`. If your code is not running on that thread, do not update your JavaFX UI from there!

Comment: @Simsala And what did I said where "time consuming" task is running?

Comment: thank you very much for your help till now. I just managed to get things running, did a Property binding to my Label and my animation is running while sending E-Mails BUT
the task currently sends E-Mails simultaneously but i want it one after another. I tried thread.join() but if I use that, my UI freezes again. Is there any solution?