# Add level in JavaFX during loading operation

Tags: javafx, loading, freeze

I have the following UI

[image]

So , you insert a keyword and then press "Cerca" (it's like Search in Italian) , then the Google Custom Search Api show the first 10 pictures. During the Custom search API are processing the results (the pictures) I want to show an other picture like this [image]

(I know it's big but the dimension is not the main point now). My idea is simple, I want to put the picture one "level"(don't know exactly how to call ) over the UI, then the picture will be not visible in 3 case: 1) When the API will end their job 2)If I don't have results 3) If I get an exception. My question is, which is the best approach to do this ? And then, Should I use Threads?

I hope I was clear

UPDATE:

This is the code of "cerca" button

```
cerca.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

//                      Task<Boolean> task = new Task <Boolean>(){
//
//                      @Override
//                      protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
//                          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//                          return null;
//                      }
//                      
//                      
//                  };




                    String searchKeyWord = userTextField.getText();
                     result = getSearchResult(searchKeyWord);


                    for ( i=0; i<result.size(); i++)

                {
                        System.out.println("" +result.get(i)); 
                        ImageView resultview;
                        resultview = new ImageView(result.get(i)); 
                        resultview.setFitWidth(130);
                        resultview.setFitHeight(130);
//                      resultview.setStyle("-fx-border:6; -fx-border-color: green;");   

                          if(j==4)
                                  {
                                    j=0;
                                    k++;
                                  }



                           resultgrid.add(resultview, j,k );
                           j++;





                    VBox vbox = new VBox();
                    resultgrid.setHgap(50);
                    resultgrid.setVgap(50);
//                  resultgrid.setStyle("-fx-border:1; -fx-border-color: red;");
                    vbox.getChildren().add(resultgrid);
                    vbox.setSpacing(10);
                    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(90, 0, 10, 220)); //TOP RIGHT BOTTOM LEFT
//                  content.setAlignment(resultgrid, Pos.TOP_RIGHT);
                    getChildren().add(vbox);


                    final int ind = i;
                    resultview.setOnMouseClicked((ev) ->{


                         if (ev.getClickCount()==2)
                         {





                             image = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(resultview.getImage(), null);
                            parent.setCrop(image);



                }


                });


                }

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html). It has [setOnSucceeded()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#setOnSucceeded-javafx.event.EventHandler-) and [setOnFailed()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#setOnFailed-javafx.event.EventHandler-) which will come handy in your case.

You can basically create a new Task when the search takes place. The search will run in background and you can show the loading UI in the screen.

- If the task completes successfully, you can load the new screen with the results.
- If the task fails, you can show an error message near the search TextField.
- In case of exception, you can catch it and write the necessary code.

Comment: Hi, nice explanation but I need an example to understand. At the moment I just create the task, like this `Task<Boolean> task = new Task <Boolean>(){

      @Override
      protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return null;
      }
      
      
     };`

Comment: @IItachiUchiha I just put the code about the "cerca" button, so in this way we can better understand each other. I have commented the code that I wrote you above

Comment: @user2556079 Creating a task inside the buttons action event is not a very good idea IMO since you are pushing a lot of code inside it. You can create a task and just start it inside the action event. Moreover, you also need to override the `setOnSucceeded()` and `setOnFailed()` which makes your event clumsy.

Comment: You can see the use of both the said methods in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658082/javafx-8-dialog-and-concurrency/33658178#33658178) .