# Opening new window from an external Thread in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I want to open a new window (Stage) in javafx from an external Thread (not from the principal Thread). my code bellow is not working, please help me.

This is my java code :

```
public void login(ActionEvent event)
{       
    Task task = new javafx.concurrent.Task<Void>()
    {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception 
            {
                loader.setVisible(true);
                if(Compte.login(username.getText(), password.getText()))
                {
                    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/PrincipalFram.fxml"));
                    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                    Stage stage = new Stage();
                    stage.setScene(scene);
                    stage.setTitle("My Title");
                    stage.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    //TODO 
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void succeeded() 
            {
                loader.setVisible(false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void failed() 
            {
                loader.setVisible(false);
            }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a background thread here? What is it here that takes time to execute? See if the general comments on multithreading in JavaFX [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249493/using-threads-to-make-database-requests) help.

Comment: I have a login button that send a request to my database which is on a server. so it's better to do it inside a thread.

Comment: OK, but then *only* that should be done inside the background thread. The UI work must be done on the FX Application Thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform *only* the time-consuming work on the background thread. All UI work *must* be done on the FX Application Thread. (The [documentation for `Stage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html) explicitly states that "Stage objects must be constructed and modified on the FX Application Thread".) So you should do:

```
public void login(ActionEvent event) {   

    Task<Boolean> loginTask = new Task<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
            return Compte.login(username.getText(), password.getText());
        }
    };

    loginTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {

        if (loginTask.getValue()) {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/PrincipalFram.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setTitle("My Title");
            stage.show();
        } else {
            //TODO 
        }
        loader.setVisible(false);
    });

    loginTask.setOnFailed(e -> {
        loader.setVisible(false);
    });

    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    loader.setVisible(true);
    thread.start();
}
```