# JavaFX Database-Query in Paralell with ProgressIndicator

Tags: sql, javafx

My Question:

I would write a program in JavaFX and I have to do two database queries in parallel. While the query is running I would like to set up a Progress indicator.

What is a good way to do this?

Thread? 
ExecutorService?

Comment: Use a [`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249493/using-threads-to-make-database-requests. (You can just do `progressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty())` for the progress bar).

Comment: Thanks, that works great.

Comment: Is it a good way to wait for result with an setOnSucceed(EventHandler) ?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct way to do it.