# fast search on a field in a Java object

Tags: java, performance, caching, search

I am not sure if my title truly reflects what I want to ask. 
I have a Java class called `Light` with a field: `private int state`. I am looking for suggestions on what would be a better / fastest way to access the "state" field as all the Light objects will be stored in a `HashMap`. (HashMap's key is int id.) and  Light.*state* gets updated frequently. An example of my operation is: get me all `Light` objects that are in `state = 2`. after I get everything in `state=2`, I might need to change a few to `state = 3`. 
I thought of bitmap, but I don't store state in the database only in the cache for faster access/modification. I am not sure how to implement bitmap on a field in an object. I am all ears on any possible solutions. 
Thanks in advance!

```
class Light {
   private int state = 0;
   ....other fields....
   public void setState(int state) {
       this.state = state;
   }
}

HashMap<Integer, Light> cache ; // Integer is id not state
```

Comment: You must manually maintain a separate index for all you want to know. A map from Integer to a Set of Light might be a good starting point.  Every time a state field is updated, you must update your index structures.

Comment: Don't worry about micro-optimizations. Focus on writing understandable code. If this select is performance-critical, you'll need some sort of index anyway.

Comment: pre-optimization is the root of all evil (or something)

Comment: is there a way to avoid having another map to store the field?

Comment: you don't need another map..chnage your cache to something like this..

`HashMap<Integer, Set<Light>> cache;` as far as I understood there can have multiple `Light` for a given state;

Comment: My bad. I didn't state my question clearly. HashMap<Integer, Light>, the Integer is for id not state. Id is the most frequent accessed key, then it's state. is there a way to utilize the existing cache to provide such search ?

Comment: You might be able to get some ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44801274/in-populating-an-observablelist-do-i-have-to-load-all-the-records-from-my-datab/44802369#44802369). Look at the "Filtering a table in Java (all objects in memory)" part.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson thanks!