# Why my stage doesn't respond while the program is running? (java fx)

Tags: java, javafx, freeze, stage

I have a simple javaFx application which is search some text and some elements from html structures. It has a little window, a stage. The program can run correctly, but while the program is running, the stage (javaFx window) does not respond, it freeze. 
I thought I should run my stage in a new thread, but it didn't work. This is my program's mentioned part. 
How can I run my program without window freeze?

```
public class Real_estate extends Application implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/house-icon.png"));
        stage.setTitle("Simple program 0.8");
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(300);
        stage.setResizable(false);

        HtmlSearch htmlSearch = new HtmlSearch ();
        htmlSearch .toDatabase("http://example.com");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the code that takes a long time to run (presumably `htmlSearch.toDatabase(...)`) in a background thread. You can do this with

```
public class Real_estate extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/house-icon.png"));
        stage.setTitle("Simple program 0.8");
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(300);
        stage.setResizable(false);

        HtmlSearch htmlSearch = new HtmlSearch ();
        new Thread(() -> htmlSearch.toDatabase("http://example.com")).start();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This assumes that `htmlSearch.toDatabase(...)` does not modify the UI; if it does, you will need to wrap the code that modifies the UI in `Platform.runLater(...)`. See, e.g. [Using threads to make database requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249493/using-threads-to-make-database-requests) for a longer explanation of multithreading in JavaFX.