# JavaFX window is not opened immediately

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, visualization

I've created a visualizer in JavaFX for a problem I'm solving, and currently I can get it to show up after the calculations in my application are done, but I would like the window to first be opened and then run the calculations, so I can animate the visualization during the computations.

This is the code for creating an instance of the problem, showing the visualizer and performing the calculations:

```
public static void run(Visualizer v) {
    readInput();
    if (v != null) {
        v.resizeCanvas(rectangles);
        v.drawAllRectangles(rectangles);
        v.show();
    }
    calculateArea();

    System.out.println(totalArea);
}
```

The `Visualizer` class extends `javafx.application.Application` and utilizes a JavaFX Canvas. `calculateArea()` simply runs a static method which performs some calculations.

What currently happens when I run my program is:

1. It waits for input on `stdin`
2. The computations are run
3. The visualization is displayed

What I want:

1. It waits for input on `stdin`
2. The visualization is displayed
3. The computations are run

So for some reason the displaying of the visualization is delayed even though I call `v.show()` before `calculateArea()`.

My first hunch would be to run the calculations in a new thread, but according to
[the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) "The JavaFX scene graph, which represents the graphical user interface of a JavaFX application, is not thread-safe and can only be accessed and modified from the UI thread also known as the JavaFX Application thread."

I tried putting a `Thread.sleep(3000)` right after `v.show()`, and what happened was that my program just waited 3 seconds before running `calculateArea()` followed by the window being displayed.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: The Task and Service classes are probably what you're looking for: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm

Comment: You're right, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249493/using-threads-to-make-database-requests), which is about accessing databases; you can use the same techniques to run your calculation in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You should call your calculation method in a separate thread (as suggested by @Selim) launched in the applications `start()` method.

If your calculation method directly changes graphical content on screen (which it should not do BTW...) you need to pass this graphics code (not the calculation itself) to `Platform.runLater()`.

Comment: I see. I understand that it's not the best to mix in graphics code into the calculation code, my idea was to just have a boolean flag to enable/disable running any eventual graphics instructions within the calculation code but I guess that's not a great way to solve it. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: @AxelKennedal *"I understand that it's not the best to mix in graphics code into the calculation code,"* Yes, it violates the *Separation of concerns / Single Responsibility* Pattern (SoC/SRP). Have a look at the *MVVM/MVVC* Pattern. JavaFX has been designed to support that.