# Java socket/JavaFX - sending mssgs makes clients stop working

Tags: java, sockets, javafx

I am trying to do checkers using java sockets. However, when I run a client, it gets stuck in a loop and stops responding.

So far my app has methods to draw a board, move checkers and create connection between a server and clients.
The connection is created correctly.

The problem is with play() which is responsible for handle server messages.

Pls help me to modify play() to have it working.

---

Client App

---

```
public class CheckersApp extends Application {

public static final int TILE_SIZE = 100;
public static final int WIDTH = 8;
public static final int HEIGHT = 8;

private Tile[][] board = new Tile[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

private Group tileGroup = new Group();
private Group pieceGroup = new Group();
private Label text = new Label();

private static int PORT = 8901;
private Socket socket;
private BufferedReader in;
private PrintWriter out;

// method to draw a board with checkers

private Parent createContent() {
        ...
}

// method to check if moving checkers is possbile
private MoveResult tryMove(Piece piece, int newX, int newY) {
      ...
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Scene scene = new Scene(createContent());
    primaryStage.setTitle("CheckersApp");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    // Setup networking
    socket = new Socket("LAP00132", PORT);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        socket.getInputStream()));
    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

    play();
}

// method to move checkers
private Piece makePiece(PieceType type, int x, int y) {
  ...
}

// method to get responses from Server
public void play() throws Exception {
    String response;
    try {
        response = in.readLine();
        if (response.startsWith("WELCOME")) {
           // char mark = response.charAt(8);
        }
        while (true) {
            response = in.readLine();
            if (response.startsWith("VALID_MOVE")) {
                text.setText("Valid move, please wait");

            } else if (response.startsWith("OPPONENT_MOVED")) {

                text.setText("Opponent moved, your turn");
            } else if (response.startsWith("VICTORY")) {
                text.setText("You win");
                break;
            } else if (response.startsWith("DEFEAT")) {
                text.setText("You lose");
                break;
            } else if (response.startsWith("TIE")) {
                text.setText("You tied");
                break;
            } else if (response.startsWith("MESSAGE")) {
                text.setText(response.substring(8));
            }
        }
        out.println("QUIT");
    }
    finally {
        socket.close();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);}
```

---

Server App

---

```
 public class Server {

/**
 * Runs the application. Pairs up clients that connect.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(8901);
    System.out.println("Server is Running");
    try {
        while (true) {
            Game game = new Game();
            Game.Player playerX = game.new Player(listener.accept(), 'X');
            System.out.println("Połączony X");
            Game.Player playerO = game.new Player(listener.accept(), 'O');
            System.out.println("Połączony O");
            playerX.setOpponent(playerO);
            playerO.setOpponent(playerX);
            game.currentPlayer = playerX;
            playerX.start();
            playerO.start();
        }
    } finally {
        listener.close();}}}
```

---

---

```
class Game {

public static final int WIDTH = 8;
public static final int HEIGHT = 8;
//private Tile[][] board = new Tile[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

Player currentPlayer;

/**
 * Called by the player threads when a player tries to make a
 * move.  This method checks to see if the move is legal: that
 * is, the player requesting the move must be the current player
 */
public synchronized boolean legalMove(Player player) {
    if (player == currentPlayer) {
        currentPlayer = currentPlayer.opponent;
        currentPlayer.otherPlayerMoved();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}



class Player extends Thread {
    char mark;
    Player opponent;
    Socket socket;
    BufferedReader input;
    PrintWriter output;

    /**
     * Constructs a handler thread for a given socket and mark
     * initializes the stream fields, displays the first two
     * welcoming messages.
     */
    public Player(Socket socket, char mark) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.mark = mark;
        try {
            input = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            output.println("WELCOME " + mark);
            System.out.println("Welcome ");
            output.println("MESSAGE Waiting for opponent to connect");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Player died: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Accepts notification of who the opponent is.
     */
    public void setOpponent(Player opponent) {
        this.opponent = opponent;
    }

    /**
     * Handles the otherPlayerMoved message.
     */
    public void otherPlayerMoved() {
        output.println("OPPONENT_MOVED ");
        System.out.println("OPPONENT_MOVED");
    }



    /**
     * The run method of this thread.
     */
    public void run() {
        try {
            // The thread is only started after everyone connects.
            output.println("MESSAGE All players connected");

            // Tell the first player that it is her turn.
            if (mark == 'X') {
                output.println("MESSAGE Your move");
            }

            // Repeatedly get commands from the client and process them.
            while (true) {
                String command = input.readLine();
                if (command.startsWith("MOVE")) {
                    if (legalMove(this)) {
                        output.println("VALID_MOVE");
                        System.out.println("VALID MOVE");
                    } else {
                        output.println("MESSAGE ?");
                    }
                } else if (command.startsWith("QUIT")) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Player died: " + e);
        } finally {
            try {socket.close();} catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Check this [brilliantly written answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30250308/1759128) to understand how background tasks work in JavaFX and how you can use it in your use-case. If things don't work out, edit your question and tell us what went wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `while(true)` loop just waits for a line. It blocks the ability to perform any actions on the UI.

Spawn a separate thread to handle server communications. Obviously you need to be aware of the dangers of multi-threading and multi-thread access of model and UI data.