# Populate TreeView and display status messages

Tags: javafx, treeview, label

I'm trying to populate my TreeView and update the text of status label before and after the populating.

my code looks something like this:

```
public void populateTreeView() {
    // start message
    this.label.setText("Process started...");

    // populate the TreeView, this takes several minutes

    // finish message
    this.label.setText("Done!");
}
```

It's not working as I expected. I tried put each of the the 3 main sections of this method in Platform.runLater() and that didn't work, too. The app just freezes for some seconds and then I see the populated TreeView and the "Done" text.

How can I get this behavior?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You should populate the TreeView in a background thread. [Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30250308/1759128) on how to correctly write JavaFX program for long running tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to execute the loading method in a background Thread. Basically, the interface that you create and all of its events are executed on the JavaFX Application Thread (JFXAT).

These events are generally executed one at a time, so if you run a long process on this Thread, the UI will appear to be frozen until that process is completed.

While there are several ways to create background tasks in JavaFX, below is a simple demo application that uses a `Task` to do so.

The example code is commented throughout to explain what we are doing. The example uses a `ListView` instead of a `TreeView`, just for simplicity, but the concept is the same regardless.

This example shows a basic interface with a `ListView` and a `Button` to start the loading process. At the bottom is a `Label` that will keep the user updated on the current step in the Task's process.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Just a simple interface
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Create the list view
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.setPrefHeight(200);

        // Status label
        Label lblStatus = new Label();

        // Here we will create a new Task that will run in the background
        Task<List<String>> loadDataTask = new Task<List<String>>() {

            // We override the call() method; this is the code that is run when the task is started. When the Task
            // is completed, it will return a new List of Strings
            @Override
            protected List<String> call() throws Exception {

                // Tasks have a messageProperty that allows us to keep the UI informed. We will bind this value to
                // our Label later
                updateMessage("Loading data ...");

                // Generate some sample data
                List<String> listOfItems = new ArrayList<>();
                listOfItems.add("One");
                listOfItems.add("Two");
                listOfItems.add("Three");
                listOfItems.add("Four");
                listOfItems.add("Five");

                // Simulate a long-running task by pausing the thread for 10 seconds
                Thread.sleep(10000);

                // Now we can update the messageProperty again and return the completed data List
                updateMessage("Finished!");

                return listOfItems;
            }
        };

        // We can now tell our application what to do once the Task has finished (either successfully or failure)
        loadDataTask.setOnFailed(wse -> {
            // This is called if an exception is thrown during the execution of the Task
            // We will just print the Exception in this sample
            loadDataTask.getException().printStackTrace();
        });

        // The Task completed successfully so lets now bind the List to our ListView
        loadDataTask.setOnSucceeded(wse -> {
            listView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(loadDataTask.getValue()));
        });

        // Now that we've defined our background Task and what to do when it's completed, let's create a button
        // that allows us to start the task.
        Button button = new Button("Load Data");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {

            // Let's bind our Label to the Task's messageProperty. This will cause the Label to update automatically
            // whenever the Task calls the updateMessage() method.
            lblStatus.textProperty().bind(loadDataTask.messageProperty());

            // Now let's start the Task on a background Thread. This will cause the rest of the UI to remain
            // responsive.
            new Thread(loadDataTask).start();
        });

        // Add the controles to the Scene
        root.getChildren().addAll(
                button,
                listView,
                new Label("Status:"),
                lblStatus);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

When the button is clicked, the background Task is executed, the `Label` is updated to show "Loading data ..." and the long-running task begins.

When the Task finishes, the `ListView` gets updated with the data and the `Label` will show `Finished!"

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! It was very helpful!