# How to wait for a JavaFX Service to finish before returning data in caller?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, service

Working on my first Java project I can't seem to get around this probably basic problem: In a `JavaFX` application I have a `DAO` class, which starts a `service` to get values from a `mysql` db, builds an object from it and returns the object to the caller. But the object never gets build, because the return happens before the service has succeeded.

```
public IQA getQA(int id) throws SQLException {      
        try {           
        GetQuizService getQuizService = new GetQuizService();
        getQuizService.restart();
        getQuizService.setId(id);
        getQuizService.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            this.quiz = getQuizService.getValue();
        });         
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    return quiz;
}
```

The service works fine, inside the onSucceeded action the object is present, but how can I make the return wait until the service has finished?

As requested here's a minimal version of the GetQuizService

```
public class GetQuizService extends Service<Quiz> {
    private int id;
    private Quiz quiz;
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<Quiz> createTask() {
        return new Task<Quiz>() {
            @Override
            protected Quiz call() throws Exception {
                // Severall calls to db here, Quiz object gets constructed
                return quiz;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `GetQuizService` code?

Comment: GetQuizService code is 100 + lines long... also it works fine. When I do a syso inside getQuizService.setOnSucceeded  I get this.quiz just fine. Its only on the return statement that I get a null.

Comment: [How to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is, that you service methods are executed asynchronously.

You should return the `Task<Quiz>` instead of `quiz` and use that to update your frontend if the result is received (I have to few information to create an appropriate example for you).

Another option is to pass a callback to your service, which is invoked when the result is received instead of returning the quiz.

```java
public void getQA(int id, QuizReceiver callback) throws SQLException {
    try {
        GetQuizService getQuizService = new GetQuizService();
        getQuizService.restart();
        getQuizService.setId(id);
        getQuizService.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            callback.quizReceived(getQuizService.getValue());
        });         
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    return quiz;
}
```

```java
public interface OuizReceiver {
    void quizReceived(IQA quiz);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In the end I think this points to an design problem in the project, which I should address.

Comment: Thanks again Samuel! For anyone interested I have found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249493/using-threads-to-make-database-requests) addresses the situation I'm facing pretty well