# Javafx UI not responding after it runs Task

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a javafx application. Since I need to display some data from my database, I came to know about using `Task` in Javafx. I tried implementing it after seeing a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249493/using-threads-to-make-database-requests) on SO. To check if it works, I am just printing a list of teams which I get from my database in a HashTable.

When I first start the application, the data is successfully fetched and it displays on my console, but when I change through scenes and try to switch back to the homepage (where the data is being fetched), the UI totally freezes and it doesn't even display the scene.

**Home.java**

```
public class Home implements Initializable {

    private Executor executor;
    private TeamsDAO teamsDAO;

@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle)  {

        try{
            teamsDAO = new TeamsDAO();
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();}

        executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(runnable -> {
            Thread th = new Thread(runnable);
            th.setDaemon(true);
            return th;
        });

        printTeams();
    }

public void printTeams() {
        Task<Hashtable<Integer, String>> displayTask = new Task<Hashtable<Integer, String>>() {
            @Override
            protected Hashtable<Integer, String> call() throws Exception {
                return teamsDAO.getTeams();
            }
        };

        displayTask.setOnFailed(e -> {
            displayTask.getException().printStackTrace();
        });

        displayTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            cricProTitle.setText(displayTask.getValue().get(2));
        });

        executor.execute(displayTask);
    }
}
```

I am using HikariCP for database connection pool with postgresql.

**TeamsDAO.java**

```
public class TeamsDAO {

    private Connection conn;

    public TeamsDAO() throws SQLException {
        this.conn = DataSource.getConnection();
    }

    public Hashtable<Integer, String> getTeams() throws SQLException {
        try (PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TEAMS")) {
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            Hashtable<Integer, String> teams = new Hashtable<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                teams.put(rs.getInt("team_id"), rs.getString("name"));
            }
            return teams;
        }
    }
}
```

No error stack trace is displayed when the UI freezes. I would like these teams to be displayed on the homepage (after the thread works successfully) . Please suggest where am I going wrong?

Comment: Maybe this will help? [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm)

Comment: Thanks, but I have already been through it. Even after changing my code according to the tutorial, the task executes successfully only once :(.

Comment: “…when I change through scenes and try to switch back to the homepage (where the data is being fetched), the UI totally freezes…”  Since that seems to be what’s causing the problem, I recommend editing your question and including the code which does that.

Comment: [mcve] please (hard-code the data fetching in the thread, sleeping as needed) ..

Comment: Run it in a debugger. Step through the code. Check what threads are blocked and where.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, the problem occurred due to switching scenes and reloading them again and again, which was creating new threads and filling up the Database connection pool.

Comment: You could [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was initiating the `TeamsDAO` object in `initialize` method, It was creating a new database connection every time I switched back to Home controller, and hence filling up the connection pool. To fix this I created a static block in **Home.java** and fetched the data I needed only once.

Updated Home.java:

```
public class Home implements Initializable {

    private static TeamsDAO teamsDAO;

    @FXML
    private BorderPane borderPane;
    @FXML
    private Label cricProTitle;
    @FXML
    private Label homepageLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label banner;
    @FXML
    private GridPane buttonContainer;

    static {
        try {
            teamsDAO = new TeamsDAO();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Task<Hashtable<Integer, String>> task = new Task<>() {
            @Override
            protected Hashtable<Integer, String> call() throws Exception {
                return teamsDAO.getTeams();
            }
        };

        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            System.out.println(task.getValue());
        });

        Thread x = new Thread(task);
        x.setDaemon(true);
        x.start();
        System.out.println(x.getState());
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle)  {
    //setting UI properties here..
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer.  You might be interested in the [eden coding guide on how to structure a JavaFX database application](https://edencoding.com/connect-javafx-with-sqlite/#how-to-structure-a-javafx-database-application).  The guide also refers to a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/edencoding/javafx-io/tree/master/sqlite) so that you can see a complete example of the suggested approach.